# Issue with Google Sheets: a cell is miscalculating the time average

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My Google Sheets is acting out. I have the same formula in two separate cells and I'm obtaining completely different values. Can someone help?
The formula causing problems is in `J126`.

Here is the Link to the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W0sufphU6s8ETO1FwDKQ3shcVCmvQv7Hz3oaPPC6o8I/edit?usp=sharing

As you notice, it's the same formula on B126 but it works fine on B126.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is a typo/mistake in cell `I76`**

Instead of `18:35` you have `18.35`.

Once that is corrected your formula

```
=IFERROR(SUM(Filter(I3:I123-K3:K123,isnumber(K3:K123))),0)+ 
 IFERROR(SUM(Filter(I3:I123-M3:M123,isnumber(M3:M123))),0)+ 
 IFERROR(SUM(Filter(I3:I123-O3:O123,isnumber(O3:O123))),0)
```

will give you a duration result of `5:34:00`